# Assertion 'value' failed on Code Blocks with linux

Tags: c, runtime-error, codeblocks, raspberry-pi3, assertion

I am sorry my bad english. I work with Raspberry pi 3's sample code. I try run sample code on Code Blocks and I work for learn. I configured debug setting based on Makefile of sample code. I configure linker setting. When I build the code on Code Blocks, it doesn't show error. But when I run code. I taked error on console. Error this:

> Font_example: /home/pi/Desktop/Font_example/main.c: 101: main:Assertion 's==0' failed.

I remarked line. Code this:

```
// Test app for VG font library.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/vgfont/bcm_host.h"
#include "/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/vgfont/vgfont.h"

static const char *strnchr(const char *str, size_t len, char c)
{
   const char *e = str + len;
   do {
      if (*str == c) {
         return str;
      }
   } while (++str < e);
   return NULL;
}

int32_t render_subtitle(GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_HANDLE img, const char *text, const int skip, const uint32_t text_size, const uint32_t y_offset)
{
   uint32_t text_length = strlen(text)-skip;
   uint32_t width=0, height=0;
   const char *split = text;
   int32_t s=0;
   int len = 0; // length of pre-subtitle
   uint32_t img_w, img_h;

   graphics_get_resource_size(img, &img_w, &img_h);

   if (text_length==0)
      return 0;
   while (split[0]) {
      s = graphics_resource_text_dimensions_ext(img, split, text_length-(split-text), &width, &height, text_size);
      if (s != 0) return s;
      if (width > img_w) {
         const char *space = strnchr(split, text_length-(split-text), ' ');
         if (!space) {
            len = split+1-text;
            split = split+1;
         } else {
            len = space-text;
            split = space+1;
         }
      } else {
         break;
      }
   }
   // split now points to last line of text. split-text = length of initial text. text_length-(split-text) is length of last line
   if (width) {
      s = graphics_resource_render_text_ext(img, (img_w - width)>>1, y_offset-height,
                                     GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_WIDTH,
                                     GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_HEIGHT,
                                     GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff), /* fg */
                                     GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0,0,0,0x80), /* bg */
                                     split, text_length-(split-text), text_size);
      if (s!=0) return s;
   }
   return render_subtitle(img, text, skip+text_length-len, text_size, y_offset - height);
}

int main(void)
{
   GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_HANDLE img;
   uint32_t width, height;
   int LAYER=1;
   bcm_host_init();
   int s;

   s = gx_graphics_init(".");
   assert(s == 0);                  //101. line

   s = graphics_get_display_size(0, &width, &height);
   assert(s == 0);

   s = gx_create_window(0, width, height, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_RGBA32, &img);
   assert(s == 0);

   // transparent before display to avoid screen flash
   graphics_resource_fill(img, 0, 0, width, height, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0,0,0,0x00));

   graphics_display_resource(img, 0, LAYER, 0, 0, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_WIDTH, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_HEIGHT, VC_DISPMAN_ROT0, 1);

   uint32_t text_size = 10;
   while (1) {
      const char *text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
      uint32_t y_offset = height-60+text_size/2;
      graphics_resource_fill(img, 0, 0, width, height, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0,0,0,0x00));
      // blue, at the top (y=40)
      graphics_resource_fill(img, 0, 40, width, 1, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0,0,0xff,0xff));

      // green, at the bottom (y=height-40)
      graphics_resource_fill(img, 0, height-40, width, 1, GRAPHICS_RGBA32(0,0xff,0,0xff));

      // draw the subtitle text
      render_subtitle(img, text, 0, text_size,  y_offset);
      graphics_update_displayed_resource(img, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      text_size += 1;
      if (text_size > 50)
         text_size = 10;
   }

   graphics_display_resource(img, 0, LAYER, 0, 0, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_WIDTH, GRAPHICS_RESOURCE_HEIGHT, VC_DISPMAN_ROT0, 0);
   graphics_delete_resource(img);

   return 0;
}
```

1- What is wrong ?
2- Why this error on console why I couldn't see during on compiler?

**NOTE:**  I can running this code on terminal (First go file and use `make` on console after use `./hello_font.bin`) work fine.

Thanks your time. Best regards.

Comment: Please, have a look at [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert). It's a macro to check things at run-time (which cannot by evaluated at compile time). `assert` is often used to check/grant that behavior of code is like expected. (There wouldn't be any need of debugging if this would always be the case automatically after successful compiling.) In your specific case, it seems that `gx_graphics_init(".");` doesn't return the expected `0`. Why? is another question (which has nothing to do with `assert`).

Comment: Concering _I can running this code on terminal_: `"."` looks like a directory to search things in. If so, it denotes current directory. So, I guess, running this from terminal, you start it in the correct directory. Running this from CodeBlocks, it is built to / executed in another directory where `"."` doesn't work properly. But, I'm just guessing...

Comment: Thank you @Scheff. I added macro(NDEBUG) of `assert` and solving my problem. It is work fine. Differently, I try this: I remove `"."` and running this code on Code Blocks. Code is work. After I running code on terminal `main.c:101:main:Assertion 's==0' failed.` error return to me on terminal. I think your guess is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments of @Scheff. You should add macro. I added NDEBUG macro (on my project build setting and added macro to tab of other compiler under options). So my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- What is wrong ?
>   2- Why this error on console why I couldn't see during on compiler?

The [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) you are using is a run-time assert.
If you want a compile-time assert, you have to use [`static_assert`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)
Using `static_assert` allows you to print your own message that will appear as compiler error.

Simple example:

```
int main()
{
    static_assert(0 == 1, "Zero is not equal to one");
}
```

Compiler output:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:3:21: error: static assertion failed: Zero is not equal to one
     static_assert(0 == 1, "Zero is not equal to one");
```